# A combinatorial problem about partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, bijective-combinatorics

A partition of $n$ is a unordered list, whose sum is exactly $n$.

The total number of $2$’s in all partitions of $n$ is equal to the total
number of singletons in all partitions of $n−1$. A singleton is a part with
multiplicity one. For instance, the partition $(7, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1)$ (which is a partition of $29$) has two $2$’s and three singletons ($7,5,1$).

It should be proved combinatorially, which means avoiding induction, recurrences, generating functions, etc., if at all possible.

Comment: *The American Mathematical Monthly* Problem 11237 (2006)

Comment: But we need a combinatorial proof.

Comment: Could you write a title giving information about the mathematical nature of the question (*"On the bijection p234 in [M]"* is not a good title)? could you emphasize more clearly what the question is?

Comment: @YCor Sorry about this, updated now.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of 2's in partitions of $n$ is the number of partitions of $n$ with several 2's labelled (for example, in your partition $(8,8,7,5,4,4,4,2,2,1)$ we may label one or two 2's).

Now about singletons. If the partition $\lambda$ of $n-1$ has $k$-th largest part as a singleton, this is equivalent to the existence of both parts $k$ and $k-1$ (that's only provided that $k>1$) in the conjugate partition. So the total number of singletons in all partitions of $n-1$ is the number of partitions of $n-1$ with parts $k$ and $k-1$ (that's for $k>1$) labelled for certain $k$.

Now the bijection is clear: if we have $m$ labelled $2$'s in the partition of $n$, replace them to labelled $m$ and $m-1$ ($m-1$ only if $m>1$), we get a properly labelled partition of $n-1$.

Comment: can you please explain your answer more specifically?

Comment: @oyyj603450138 I am sorry, this was complete nonsense. Now looks fine.

Comment: you may misunderstand the problem. sorry for the confusing description before, now the description has been updated.

Comment: @oyyj603450138 I did misread the problem, now should be ok.